# Call external json webservice from asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json

I need to make a call to a json webservice from C# Asp.net. The service returns a json object and the json data that the webservice wants look like this:

```
"data" : "my data"
```

This is what I've come up with but I can't understand how I add the data to my request and send it and then parse the json data that I get back.

```
string data = "test";
Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost/Service.svc/json");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
string postData = "{\"data\":\"" + data + "\"}";
```

How can I add my json data to my request and then parse the response?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console/8270482#8270482

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net), to deserialize/parse the data. You can get the data using:

```
// corrected to WebRequest from HttpWebRequest
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/service.svc/json");

request.Method="POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
string postData = "{\"data\":\"" + data + "\"}"; //encode your data 
                                               //using the javascript serializer

//get a reference to the request-stream, and write the postData to it
using(Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
        sw.Write(postData);
}

//get response-stream, and use a streamReader to read the content
using(Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        var jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //decode jsonData with javascript serializer
    }
}
```