# json to call a method

Tags: c#, json, asp-classic, asp.net-ajax

I am new JSON. I have written a code like below to call a method in c#. But its not yet all calling the method. Please show me a solution how to call a method with n without parameters

```
$.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"~/PageName.aspx/test",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
           alert("s");
       },error: function(msg){
           alert("error" + msg);
       }

       })
```

C#

```
public void test()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the above if the method is behind the aspx page.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string test()
   {

   }
```

You can also use  [pagemethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

check these two places you will get solution to problem

[Best way to call a JSON WebService from a .NET Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console)

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233698/Consuming-a-Json-WebService-from-a-Csharp-or-VB-Ap

Comment: I think that Srujan0228 need to consume the webmethod from a aspx page. The examples you posted saying about consume service with WebRequest.