# how to call JSON WebService from a .NET Console

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am trying to consume JSON web service in c# console application. 
web service is using HTTP basic authentication. I am unable to access in my console application.

Code sample...

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://0000.000.0.000:0000/hrms/rest/login");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = @"application/json";
//request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("sharads:hrms123"));
HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: What exception do you get exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console

Comment: Have you tried [json.net](http://json.net). Makes things a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to send HTTP request to JSON Webservice. For example

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic", 
        Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "yourusername", "yourpwd"))));


HttpResponseMessage reponse = httpClient.GetAsync("api/enumproducts/GetAll").Result;
if (reponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var enumProducts = reponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<EnumProduct>>().Result;
}
```

HttpClient supports also POST Action. For more Details you can take a look at this [blog post](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-consume-asp-net-web-api-rc-with-httpclient/)