# How To Read A JSON String From A Webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, json, web

I am trying to download the contents of [this](https://api.fixer.io/latest) webpage into my program. I have tried using `WeblClient.DownloadString`, `WebClient.DownloadFile`, then save it to a file and read it from a local file, but none of this is working. When I use breakpoints in Visual Studio, I see the string is correctly saved, but when I try to print it to a file, or print it to the console, nothing is displayed.

What I am aiming to do is download this webpage's content into a String then parse it with JSON.NET.

Here is my attempt to save it to a file:

```
         WebClient webpage = new WebClient();


         var html = webpage.DownloadString("https://api.fixer.io/latest");
         String k = html;


          File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\JCena\Desktop\Hell1o.txt", k);
```

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: The link is borken, But if it return pure JSON You can use `RestSharp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to call a JSON WebService from a .NET Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is almost fine.
first, get rid of the "new" keyword.
second, make sure you don't have exception for permissions for the folder specified.

try that code:

```
     WebClient webpage = new WebClient();

     var html = webpage.DownloadString("https://api.fixer.io/");
     String k = html;

     File.WriteAllText(@"Hello.txt", k);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! The "new" isn't actually in my code, I accidently copy pasted the wrong line and forgot to edit it out :P

Comment: Does it work for you now?
If it is the answer you were looking for, mark it as "answer".
otherwise, help me help you :)

Comment: No :( No file is being written for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: No exception for some reason... The file is just not being written with no errors or anything.

Comment: 1. Did you used the exact code I've put here?
2. Try to turn on all of the exception in the Exception Settings (Debug->Windows->exception settings). and run your code again.

Comment: Yep, I used your exact code and have all exceptions turned on.

Comment: And the if you write it to the console. still nothing?
`Console.Writeline(k)`

Comment: Ok, so I rebooted Visual Studio as an admin and that seemed to work. Seeing as your code worked, I will mark yours as the solution :)