# Elasticsearch as service setup

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

How can I call elastic search from .NET console app, when I've set it up as Windows service? All tutorials online have it running as http://localhost:9200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch is designed to be interacted with through its RESTful API, so you will need to make REST calls to it from your app. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console) of a C# REST call. Here is Elasticsearch's RESTful [documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html). Hope this helps.