# How can I console itens from a JSON object using c#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to log some items from a JSON object, that I'm getting from an API, to the console using c# with the following code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office.CustomUI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

    static void GetCoinValues()
    {

        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/");

        List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + item.id.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.name.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Symbol: " + item.symbol.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Rank: " + item.rank.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Price (USD): " + item.price_usd.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
```

Wich I got from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104016/11234800

But I keep getting the same error code "CS1061", for all the items I'm trying to print:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Item' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no accessible extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'Item' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ApiTesting  C:\Users\raschmitt\source\repos\raschmitt\tranigcsharp\17_10\ApiTesting\ApiTesting\Program.cs   28  Active

What am I doing wrong, and how I can correct it?

Comment: What does your `Item` class look like?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to declare it, my bad. Just did it as suggested in the link provided and now it works just fine.