# How to use Dwolla with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopping-cart, dwolla

I am trying to use new Dwolla payment method for the customers for my already built Ecommerce Site .

Dwolla site doesn't provide sample code or directions to integrate it to ASP.NET .

Can anybody help in providing markers and sample code to integrate it to my ecommerce site in the simplest way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you exact details as I don't do ASP.NET, but here's a few resources:

To send a request from asp.net:

[Call external json webservice from asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071097/call-external-json-webservice-from-asp-net-c-sharp)

An example dwolla API endpoint:

https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/send

Your post request would look something like:

```
POST https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/transactions/send
Content-Type: application/json 

{
    "oauth_token": "",
    "pin": "",
    "destinationId": "",
    "amount": "",
    "destinationType": "Dwolla",
    "assumeCosts": "false",
    "additionalFees": []
}
```

Of course, to do this you would need the user's api token, and they'd need to enter their pin.