# NHibernate generate mappings from classes?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Is there a way to generate mappings for NHibernate from POCO? This [reply to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361996/what-sql-orm-may-i-use-to-replace-this-old-code/2362080#2362080) makes NHibernate look very interesting. However i have a lot of classes that look like this

```
public class register_email_job
{
    public PK id;
    public user_data user;
}

public class user_comment : BaseComment2
{
    [IsNullable]
    public user_comment parent;
    public user_data user;
}
```

I would like to easily translate this into something compatible with NHibernate. I wouldnbt mind modifying some queries but i prefer not to rewrite each class to use properties and modify class in such a way i need to change how its used everywhere.

-edit- Note that i use inheritance and user_comment has an object to user_comment (thus why it must be nullable. so it doesn't infinitely recurse. null is root).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the Auto Mapping abilities of Fluent NHibernate: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

Answer (score 0):

In order for NHibernate to construct proxies for your entity classes, you will need to make your non-private members virtual. Public fields will not work with proxy objects, these should be converted to properties.

```
public class register_email_job
{
    public virtual PK id { get; set; }
    public virtual user_data user { get; set; }
}
```

[Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) is able to create mapping from classes. It can [automap](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) based on conventions, or you can write your own [mappers](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping).

Your entities and tables may not match the default [conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions), there a several ways to override them.

Using classmap, your mapping might look like this:

```
public class register_email_job_map : ClassMap<register_email_job>
{
    public register_email_job_map()
    {
        Id( x => x.Id );
        References( x=> x.user );
    }
}

public class user_comment_map : ClassMap<user_comment>
{
    public register_email_job_map()
    {
        // properties from BaseComment2
        References( x=> x.user );
        References( x=> x.parent );
    }
}
```

Comment: ugh, this looks like it will take massive work. There are dozens of classes. All simple. Maybe i should take my existing reflection code and tweak it to output mappings. But, this question should go on.