# Parsing Facebook Open Graph API JSON Response in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, facebook

I try to get parse JSON response for the following link:
https://graph.facebook.com/feed/?ids=135395949809348,149531474996&access_token=

The response is like that:

```
{
   "135395949809348": {
      "data": [
         {
             ....Some data
         }]
     }
,
   "325475509465": {
      "data": [
         {
       ....Some data......
      }]
    }
}
```

I use  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(string json) method.
But the objects key names always different , so I can't define the  class that can be used for parsing this response.
Is anyone has any experience in parsing multiple id's response from Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JSON.NET you can read the respose as JObject and then access it via indexer.

```
var json = JObject.Parse(result);
var array = json["325475509465"]["data"];
```

Then you can deserialize objects from array...

Answer (score 1):

What is your issue with the Deserialize?  Deserialize is going to produce a Dictionary, with potential inner arrays and dictionary instances too....

It wouldn't parse as a custom object unless you build a serializer to do that... or look at JSON.NET: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I use the similar method as described here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net
But, in my case I can't define "135395949809348" object.

Comment: Right, but you may want to try the Dictionary<string, object> approach, deserialize it to a dictionary and extract the information that way.  Bit of a pain, but this scenario would be handled.