# Search result display in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi I am currently working on Search feature of Facebook Graph API using C# SDK.

Since C# SDK source does't provide any example for this, I found below on web, which works well.

```
Dictionary<string, object> searchParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
searchParams.Add("type", "post");
searchParams.Add("q", "olympic");
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(token);
var rslt = fbClient.Get("/search", searchParams);
```

I get the rslt and I can see string with many differnt parameters in double quotes and lots of brackets and parenthesis.

Does anyone have an idea if there is proper way of displaying this result ?
I am not guessing manual parsing, but putting into some method in Facebook library or viewing directly using some sort of conversion media..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not want to answer my own question, however for the sake of whoever having similar issues.

I found two related posts, realizing what I am dealing with is JSON format.

They encourage to use JObject, JSON.NET.

[Parsing Facebook Open Graph API JSON Response in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248267/parsing-facebook-open-graph-api-json-response-in-c-sharp)

[How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)