# Parse a JSON query response string in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json

Hey guys I have the following code working which is sending a GET Request and receiving JSON Response.

Now I can basically go

GetWeatherByLocation(53.3, -6.28);

and the method returns

{"status":"OK","url":"http://www.link.com/areas/rathfarnham-11","name":"Rathfarnham"}

I was now wondering how can I retrieve the values for

- URL
- Name

from the string returned

THanks a lot

Im using ASP.NET 2 this is my calling code

```
public static string GetWeatherByLocation(double lat, double lng)
{

    string formattedUri = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,

                          FindNearbyWeatherUrl, lat, lng);



    HttpWebRequest webRequest = GetWebRequest(formattedUri);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    string jsonResponse = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {

        jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

    }

    return jsonResponse;

}
```

Comment: Answer edited to take the new info into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calling code is in javascript, i guess. Just use the response as a javascript object, because the json format **is** a notation for a javascript object. You can access its properties directly:

```
var returningValue = {"status":"OK","url":"http://www.link.com/areas/rathfarnham-11","name":"Rathfarnham"} ;
alert(returningValue.status);
alert(returningValue.url);
alert(returningValue.name);
```

---

edit: if you want to parse json in .net you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net) where somebody explains how to parse the object using `JavaScriptSerializer` from `System.Web.Extensions.dll`

---

edit 2: if your version of .net doesn't let you play with this .dll i'd recommend looking into [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) previous releases, notably [the last 2.0 release](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/13099). But you should have access to the dll since it appeared in .net 2.0, albeit in the AJAX framework if my memory is good...

It's possible to parse your object by hand, but i'd really recommend using a library instead. If you want to do it by hand, you're in a complex world...

Comment: [code]public static string GetWeatherByLocation(double lat, double lng)
    {

        string formattedUri = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,

                              FindNearbyWeatherUrl, lat, lng);



        HttpWebRequest webRequest = GetWebRequest(formattedUri);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        string jsonResponse = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

        }

        return jsonResponse;

    }[/code]

Comment: Seems that DLL is for ASP.NET 3.5, is there a way I can achieve this in ASP.NET ? Its only a simple string im trying to parse really i.e {"status":"OK","url":"http://www.link.com/areas/rathfarnham-11","name":"Rathfarnham"}

Comment: Just banging my head of the wall with this stuff....ok I installed JSON.NET for ASP.NET 2 and now I have JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(DayOfWeek2);

Comment: But I still end up with same result {"status":"OK","url":"http://www.link.com/areas/rathfarnham-11","name":"Rathfarnham"}  How Can I access "URL" and "NAME" values in this string ?