# JSON to string array in C#

Tags: c#, string, json

I have JSON string just like that

```
[
    {
        "markers": {
            "0": "13.775801,100.611199",
            "1": "13.775801,100.611199" 
        } 
    }
]
```

I would like to do markers list with string array.My JSON format is exactly same with that format.It might not be change anymore.How can I do for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JavaScriptSerializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is a good option. It is in *.NET Framework v3.5*, so you won't need any *3rd Party* library.

[Here](http://atsung.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/javascriptserializer-example/) is an small example of how you can use it, although if you enter **JavaScriptSerializer** on Google, you will have lots of examples of how to parse it.

Basically, you need to define a type that fits the JSON format you need to parse, and use the `Deserialize` method of `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

**Edit:**

See @Marc Gravell's answer for a similar question: [Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or you can try a bit easy to learn library on codeplex [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Hope this helps,

Regards