# converting an array in a json string into a list

Tags: c#

I have an array in a json string like this:

```
"TheArray": "1,2,3,4,5"
```

What's the best way convert this into a list of int?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string theArray = "1,2,3,4,5";

List<int> theList = (
  from string s in theArray.Split(',') 
  select Convert.ToInt32(s)
).ToList<int>();
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I have another instance where I need to convert to a list of floats but the Convert. method doesn't show floats in the intellisense. The numbers are timezones and some timezones are 3.5 for instance; is using a float the best option and if so, how do I create a list of floats?

Comment: One more thing, you might want to add a bit of error protection, such as using TryParse: List<int> theList = (from string s in theArray.Split(',') 
                select 
                int.TryParse(s,out element) ? element : 0
            ).ToList<int>();

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.Net or JavascriptSerializer, something like:

```
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonStr);
```

and then you can get out `TheArray` from that.

The `TheArray` in your question is not exactly a JSON array, so you will have to parse the string like other answers suggested after you get value of `TheArray`

http://www.nateirwin.net/2008/11/20/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet/

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

[Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method:

```
var items = myObj.TheArray.split(',');

items[0] == "1" // true
```

Comment: I think this is step one, but it still leaves the elements in the array as strings.

Comment: In that case, all you have to do is call `parseInt(value)` on each element of the array and assign it back to the array. JavaScript is flexible that unless you need it to be an integer exactly, 1 == "1". The same is not the case for 1 === "1".

Comment: ahhh... Yes, very true... I assumed he was doing this in C#, on the back end... But yes in javascript you are correct...