# What is the best way to represent List in XML for a RESTful Service so that it will be easier to deserialize

Tags: c#, java, xml, rest

I use two programming languages: Java and C#, and the two communicating through a RESTful service. From Java, I sent some XML for a request made by the C# program, and the response for the GET include some list structure.

```
<X>
    <A>[3, 18, 11, 8, 19, 6]</A>
</X>
<X>
    <A>[3, 18, 11, 8, 19, 6]</A>
</X>
```

I have a difficult time parsing the string back into the list, not really difficult, but so manual. What I do is:

```
    public RoutingResults(String A) 
    {
        A = A.Replace("[", "");
        A = A.Replace("]", "");
        A = A.Replace(" ", "");
        String[] As = A.Split(new String[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        this.A = new List<string>();
        foreach (String ax in As)
        {
            this.As.Add(ax);
        }
    }
```

I think the code above is so funny, don't you think so? I feel so embarrassed if someone would someday hack into my PC and know that I had to code something that way. Haha.

So my question is, especially to you who are experienced with RESTful, and REST world, and XML, and anything is in that part of technology; what would be the ideal way to represent list in the XML for REST, and it would later be ideal as well to deserialize. Please give certain code to exemplify, whether in C# xor Java.

If I had to sent the response like this:

```
 <X>
      <A>
          <as>3</as>
          <as>18</as>
          <as>11</as>
          <as>8</as>
          <as>19</as>
          <as>6</as>
      <A>
 </X>
```

I think sending data like the above format would impose a performance penalty; compared if data is formatted neatly, just a .toString representation of a typical java.util.List. Don't you think so?

Comment: Why don't you use XmlSerializer and let it do all the work?

Comment: yes. you mean to parse the data into classes rite? I do use the XmlSerializer to deserialize it, and can get back that 'list', the [3, 18, 11, 8, 19, 6]. But I find it like error-prone code to transform it back to C#'s List.

Comment: I'll look into XElement man.

Comment: No. XElement is not likely what I am looking for. I use XmlSerializer to deserialize my whole XML into class.

Comment: @AdamPahleviBaihaqi why don't you use json. your list would be `{"A":[3,18,11,8,19,6]}`

Comment: I don't know man, I just feel at home and awesome using XML. No body using XML nowadays? And it is not hard to define the XSD, and then, why not? If I used JSON, would it be easier to turns it back into list in the host language (say, C#)? What I not really like about JSON is, I can't verify the types, constraint, and etc that in future I might need that capability.

Comment: If you want to use XML then you will have to put up with the extra XML tags... not much of a way around that! If you dislike JSON and XML then your existing solution is probably best.

Comment: @AdamPahleviBaihaqi of course you can use this but if you can, better let the serializers do it for you. **string input = "[3, 18, 11, 8, 19, 6]";
    List<int> numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value))
                            .ToList();**

Comment: @And also see this **var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(input);**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have said there is much wrong with the original code to be honest. It does the job, it's only a few lines and it's clear how it does it. You could change the last bit to:

```
this.A = new List<string>(As);
```

...as the constructor of `List<T>` is able to take an array as an input and populate itself automatically.

You could also look into sending it as a JSON array, which would be similar and would not involve a lot of extra XML tags. See [converting an array in a json string into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888144/converting-an-array-in-a-json-string-into-a-list).

Comment: Oh I see. Cool. I just think that this is error prone, because if my list in the future include a space, everything will be broken, and no one could easily know where the bug is. Or if some space not supposed to be replaced().

Comment: Any spaces will be caught by the Replace method so that isn't a worry. You could change your `A` field/property so that it is of type `List<int>` and then use `int.TryParse` to parse the strings into ints. That way you could deal with malformed input. You could also then do a range check to make sure they are sensible values: >0, etc.

Comment: If you were to use a JSON parser from that method then any exceptions/errors would still be raised in that method, so you would not gain/lose anything per se in terms of locating errors.