# JavaScriptSerializer on JSON containing an array

Tags: c#, arrays, javascriptserializer

I have a string of JSON like this:

```
{
    "letterstats":[
        {"time_taken":636,"mistake_letters":"","the_letter":"L","success":true},
        {"time_taken":216,"mistake_letters":"","the_letter":"U","success":true},
        {"time_taken":103,"mistake_letters":"","the_letter":"I","success":true}
    ],
    "word":"TEST"
}
```

I'm trying to use the JavaScriptSerializer to parse this, but I'm having an issue.  Here's the c# code I'm using to attempt to parse this:

```
public class wordStats
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    List<letterStats> letterstats { get; set; }
    public wordStats() { letterstats = new List<letterStats>(); }
}

public class letterStats
{
    public int time_taken { get; set; }
    public string mistake_letters { get; set; }
    public string the_letter { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
wordStats ws = ser.Deserialize<wordStats>(jsonObj);
```

It's parsing out the word fine ("TEST") but is not parsing the array.  I'm not sure whats going on, and I'm referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net/402694#402694) in order to get it to work.  Does anyone have any idea of what's going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `letterstats` property is private.

```
public class wordStats
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public List<letterStats> letterstats { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @JesseB, no matter, that was merely an oversight.

Comment: I had a similar issue except I had a private setter for the List<> property...  Had to remove private.