# convert string to json

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

```
string []a=new string[2];
a[0]="[";
a[1]="/";
```

Net3.5

how can convert `a` to json array?By C#

Comment: Search is your friend. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net/402694#402694

Comment: convert string array to json array?????

Comment: what framework do you want use this code in ? in MVC inside the action method just `retun Json(a);` that's all.

Comment: aps.net i do not use mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few Json libraries + links for you that look very good.

http://json.codeplex.com/

http://www.json.org/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/fastJSON.aspx