# how can i extract 2 values from a text string?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net)

I want to pull two values from this test string and save then as their own strings, the values I want our the first and second values in the following piece of text, the values for distance and duration, they are 178331, and 7761.  The string I want to pull them from is as follows.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "1508-1520 38th Ave, Oakland, CA 94601, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "800-828 Mountain Ranch Rd, San Andreas, CA 95249, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "111 mi",
                  "value" : 178331
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 9 mins",
                  "value" : 7761
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: That smells like JSON, there are several good JSON parsers out there (both as part of the framework and third party).  Just a thought.

Comment: Looks like the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net) is what you need as well.

Comment: At least he didn't mention regex!

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is definitely JSON and should be treated as such. To get the data you need to parse this.
Try parsing using either the built in `JavaScriptSerializer` class or JSON.NET.
(for more information, as pointed out by Shadow Wizard: [Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net))

Comment: JSON.NET is 3rd party, I think you accidentally reversed them in your answer

Comment: @James You're right, I'll fix this.