# Deserialization for JSON string containing Array collection

Tags: json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

I am using "JavaScriptSerializer" to Deserialize a Json string. This Json string contains collection of array like

```
{ "data": [
    // **
    { "id": "1234",
      "from": {
        "name": "abc",
        "id": "000041"
      },
      "message": "user message",
      "updated_time": "2011-10-06T10:14:18+0000",
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          { "id": "94387930",
            "name": "XXXX"
          }
        ]
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          { "id": "7127141",
            "from": {
              "name": "YYYYY",
              "id": "888888"
            },
            "message": "comment message",
            "created_time": "2011-10-06T10:20:44+0000"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    // **
  ]
}
```

The section surrounded by `**` is repeated N times. Please help me figure out how to deserialize this JSON.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this output, it looks like a proper JSON/JavaScript object. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Yes this is a proper JSON. As mentioned above the section within ** is repeated more than one time. its look like collection of array.I am facing problem in JavaScriptSerializer Deserialization. Give me some idea to Deserialization using JavaScriptSerializer as Deserializer doesn't accept Array type object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "deserialize", but you can use this object straight on, for example:

```
var jData = {...your json...};
for(var i = 0; i < jData.data.length; i++)
{
    document.write(jData.data[i].id + '<br />');
}
```

Check out this fiddle for full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nJ369/1/

If you wish to parse the JSON output from ASP.Net code-behind, you could use a JSON parsing library like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), or any listed on [the official JSON website](http://www.json.org/) under C#.

Comment: Can you provide solution in ASP.NET. Sorry to mention earlier.

Comment: Do you want to use this JSON object in ASP.Net code-behind or in JavaScript?

Comment: There are questions on this very site that may help you with this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net