# JSON.NET: where is the JObject class in latest version and how to use it?

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

Im starting to use this library: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx
I downloaded the latest version here: http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/74287#DownloadId=287841

It seemed to me one of the advantages of JSON.NET is that I dont have to create a class in which I have to add a property for each field I want to deserialize from the JSON response.
Which with normal asp.net deserialization would be the case (see Foo class example here: [Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net))

But here: [Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net)
it can be seen that a new object is created: JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

But where in the latest version of JSON.NET is that class defined?

Can anyone give me an example how to use JSON.NET correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: Dim o As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
lblUserId.Text = o("id").ToString