# C# string splitting elegant solution

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Looking for advice and elegant solution extracting properties and values into any convenient data structure.

```
Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Solution is to having something sort of:

```
 List<string1, string2> where string1=Path, string2=SelectedValue
```

**EDIT:**

is it possible to make it GENERIC, to understand both ways current one and:

```
Command="{Binding ExecuteSearchCommand}
```

Comment: you want to dynamically generate bindings based on a list of paths?

Comment: This screams "Regular expressions"

Comment: This looks like a [XAML binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx). Is it? If so, do you need to be able to parse the whole possible set of values or just the explicit example you give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+)=(\w+)").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new 
        { 
            Property = m.Groups[1].Value, 
            Value = m.Groups[2].Value 
        });
```

Comment: Wouldn't group 1 be "Path=SelectedValue,Mode"? Regexes are greedy by default (at least in Perl).

Comment: @m0skit0, `\w` is alphanumeric or underscore. Therefore it won't match `,`.

Comment: Granted, the OP didn't tell yet, but if this is indeed about [XAML bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx#Path_Syntax), there is much more than "\w+" to consider as key/value.

Comment: @Christian.K, Right. Something like `[^=]` instead of `\w`

Comment: Actually is it possible to make it generic? say understand both ways, current one and     Command="{Binding ExecuteSearchCommand}

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option to reformat your string slightly so it matches the JSON spec (i.e. replace your = with :, then you could use one of the following techniques):

[Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net)

[Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)