# What specific classes we have to form for this simple json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

How can we parse this simple json using proper class & member variables

```
{
"item": [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Johnny"
    },

    {   "id":13,
        "name":"mohit"
    }
        ]
 }
```

Comment: Found another similar question which has a great answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net

Comment: i did'nt get that..it is too complicated..i want to make it simple..using 2 classes

Comment: & also in previous example..item that is parsed is not multiple..i need to parse multiple items

Comment: Or maybe you can just try to go with Json.Net http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: And a "please" would be nice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+deserialization

Comment: How i iterate through multiple items..i m confused with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously u can use the Newtonsoft.Json(Json.NET)
and call a method return with a anonymous type.
like this:

```
                var anType = new
                {
                    multiResult = new
                    {
                        results = new[]
                        {
                          new 
                          {
                            description = string.Empty,
                            title = string.Empty,
                            picUrl = string.Empty,
                            totalTime = 0,
                            outerPlayerUrl = string.Empty,
                            picChoiceUrl = new string[] { "", "" }
                          }
                        }
                    }
                };

                //get info from JsonString
                var tudou = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString, anType);

                return VideoDetail.CreateSimpleInstance(DateTime.Now,
                    tudou.multiResult.results[0].title,
                    tudou.multiResult.results[0].description,
                    tudou.multiResult.results[0].picUrl,
                    tudou.multiResult.results[0].outerPlayerUrl);
            }
```