# C# Deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

> {"result":1,"message":"Client app
>   loaded","extras":{"jobs":{"5":{"jobName":"Ford Otomobil
>   Afi\u015fi","jobMaxIdleTime":"2060","jobMaxTime":"2040"}},"customers":{"8":"Seker
>   LTD"}}}

```
public class Extras
        {
            public string loginID { get; set; }
            public string loginToken { get; set; }
            public string employeesNameSurname { get; set; }
            public string employeesLanguage { get; set; }

            public Dictionary<string, string> jobs { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> customers { get; set; }

        }

 public class Dict
        {
            public int result { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
            public Extras extras { get; set; }

        }
```

> public Dictionary jobs { get; set; } // ERROR

I can not get data from "Jobs"

Comment: Please make clear what it is you want to do and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net/402694#402694) regarding this. See if this is of any help to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace {

    [Serializable]
     class  {

        public int Result;
        public string Message;
        public Extras Extras;

        //Empty Constructor
        public (){}

        public string Serialize()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
        public static  FromJson(string json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(json);
        }
    }


    [Serializable]
     class 5 {

        public string JobName;
        public string JobMaxIdleTime;
        public string JobMaxTime;

        //Empty Constructor
        public 5(){}

    }


    [Serializable]
     class Jobs {

        public 5 5;

        //Empty Constructor
        public Jobs(){}

    }


    [Serializable]
     class Customers {

        public string 8;

        //Empty Constructor
        public Customers(){}

    }


    [Serializable]
     class Extras {

        public Jobs Jobs;
        public Customers Customers;

        //Empty Constructor
        public Extras(){}

    }

}
```

Comment: System.Web.Script.Serialization anywhere using the project using. Can you use it?