# How to get json string from the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2010

The url is : http://reportguru.webdenza.com/vdetect-pro-2/api.php?q={%22svc%22:%22avl_evts%22,%22app%22:%22hst%22,%22sid%22:%22e93c3c3fbc1e3add3a518ca9d3f28d65%22}

The url contains the following json string.

```
{
"tm": 1395378731,
"events": [
    {
        "i": 828930,
        "t": "u",
        "d": {
            "prms": {
                "battery_charge": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in1": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in10": 1395374632,
                "in11": 1395374632,
                "in12": 1395374632,
                "in13": 1395374632,
                "in14": 1395374632,
                "in15": 1395374632,
                "in16": 1395374632,
                "in17": 1395374632,
                "in18": 1395374632,
                "in19": 1395374632,
                "in2": 1395374632,
                "in20": 1395374632,
                "in21": 1395374632,
                "in22": 1395374632,
                "in23": 1395374632,
                "in24": 1395374632,
                "in25": 1395374632,
                "in26": 1395374632,
                "in27": 1395374632,
                "in28": 1395374632,
                "in29": 1395374632,
                "in3": 1395374632,
                "in30": 1395374632,
                "in31": 1395374632,
                "in32": 1395374632,
                "in4": 1395374632,
                "in5": 1395374632,
                "in6": 1395374632,
                "in7": 1395374632,
                "in8": 1395374632,
                "in9": 1395374632,
                "param179": 1395374632,
                "param180": 1395374632,
                "param250": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "posinfo": {
                    "v": {
                        "y": 24.9639728,
                        "x": 55.202432,
                        "z": 57,
                        "c": 0,
                        "sc": 9
                    },
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "speed": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "i": 828930,
        "t": "m",
        "d": {
            "t": 1395374507,
            "f": 3,
            "tp": "ud",
            "pos": {
                "y": 24.9655744,
                "x": 55.2024064,
                "z": 25,
                "s": 7,
                "c": 164,
                "sc": 10
            },
            "i": 1,
            "p": {
                "battery_charge": 1,
                "param179": 0,
                "param180": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "i": 828930,
        "t": "u",
        "d": {
            "prms": {
                "battery_charge": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in1": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in10": 1395374632,
                "in11": 1395374632,
                "in12": 1395374632,
                "in13": 1395374632,
                "in14": 1395374632,
                "in15": 1395374632,
                "in16": 1395374632,
                "in17": 1395374632,
                "in18": 1395374632,
                "in19": 1395374632,
                "in2": 1395374632,
                "in20": 1395374632,
                "in21": 1395374632,
                "in22": 1395374632,
                "in23": 1395374632,
                "in24": 1395374632,
                "in25": 1395374632,
                "in26": 1395374632,
                "in27": 1395374632,
                "in28": 1395374632,
                "in29": 1395374632,
                "in3": 1395374632,
                "in30": 1395374632,
                "in31": 1395374632,
                "in32": 1395374632,
                "in4": 1395374632,
                "in5": 1395374632,
                "in6": 1395374632,
                "in7": 1395374632,
                "in8": 1395374632,
                "in9": 1395374632,
                "param179": 1395374632,
                "param180": 1395374632,
                "param250": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "posinfo": {
                    "v": {
                        "y": 24.9639728,
                        "x": 55.202432,
                        "z": 57,
                        "c": 0,
                        "sc": 9
                    },
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "speed": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "i": 828930,
        "t": "m",
        "d": {
            "t": 1395374504,
            "f": 3,
            "tp": "ud",
            "pos": {
                "y": 24.9656512,
                "x": 55.2023744,
                "z": 24,
                "s": 17,
                "c": 130,
                "sc": 10
            },
            "i": 1,
            "p": {
                "battery_charge": 1,
                "param179": 0,
                "param180": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "i": 828930,
        "t": "u",
        "d": {
            "prms": {
                "battery_charge": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in1": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "in10": 1395374632,
                "in11": 1395374632,
                "in12": 1395374632,
                "in13": 1395374632,
                "in14": 1395374632,
                "in15": 1395374632,
                "in16": 1395374632,
                "in17": 1395374632,
                "in18": 1395374632,
                "in19": 1395374632,
                "in2": 1395374632,
                "in20": 1395374632,
                "in21": 1395374632,
                "in22": 1395374632,
                "in23": 1395374632,
                "in24": 1395374632,
                "in25": 1395374632,
                "in26": 1395374632,
                "in27": 1395374632,
                "in28": 1395374632,
                "in29": 1395374632,
                "in3": 1395374632,
                "in30": 1395374632,
                "in31": 1395374632,
                "in32": 1395374632,
                "in4": 1395374632,
                "in5": 1395374632,
                "in6": 1395374632,
                "in7": 1395374632,
                "in8": 1395374632,
                "in9": 1395374632,
                "param179": 1395374632,
                "param180": 1395374632,
                "param250": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "posinfo": {
                    "v": {
                        "y": 24.9639728,
                        "x": 55.202432,
                        "z": 57,
                        "c": 0,
                        "sc": 9
                    },
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                },
                "speed": {
                    "v": 0,
                    "ct": 1395374632,
                    "at": 1395374632
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "i": 828930,
        "t": "m",
        "d": {
            "t": 1395374632,
            "f": 3,
            "tp": "ud",
            "pos": {
                "y": 24.9639728,
                "x": 55.202432,
                "z": 57,
                "s": 0,
                "c": 0,
                "sc": 9
            },
            "i": 0,
            "p": {
                "param179": 0,
                "param180": 0,
                "param250": 0,
                "battery_charge": 0
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Please help me how will I get the string and get the data in Asp.net(c#).

Comment: I am getting error during parsing.I am getting Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 3, position 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# is provide WebClient class in System.Net get string using this class like

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
```

Answer (score 2):

get string from url

```
string Strjson = new WebClient().DownloadString(UrlQuery);
```

convert json string to Class Object

```
 ClsObject = (ClsObject) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Strjson);
```

or

```
ClsObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Strjson,ClsObject);
```

Needs to add the Newtonsoft library to your project

Download [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript Serializer for this.

See following question answer.
[Parsing JSON using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net)

Comment: var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var rawJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);// I am getting error during parsing.

Comment: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 3, position 1.

Comment: There is some problem with JSON you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

text from url can be read using WebClient. This result can be changed to object notation using javascriptSerializer.

Comment: I tried the same but json is coming null.I tried the following code.   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://reportguru.webdenza.com/vdetect-pro-2/api.php?q={\"svc\":\"avl_evts\",\"app\":'" + p_type + "',\"sid\":'" + sid + "'}");
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var json = ExtractJsonResponse(response);

Comment: I have two urls.In the first url the string is coming.In 2nd one which I mentioned it is not working.

Comment: Then its the problem with JSON you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the task down into steps,.

First get the URL in string format

string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

Then you need to pull the JSON formatted data and place it into a file (save)

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\url.json", url);

You might have to serialize it using the Newtonsoft JSON.Net framework. But, I believe that's the jist of it.