# How to parse JSON objects with numeric keys using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I have an object like below to be deserialized in C#.  I am wondering how I can parse it.  I tried following [this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net), but am stumped on how I can get my class to recognize the key of each object (the `2` and the `3` below).

The JSON string below basically represents 2 transactions.  I would like to convert each transaction representation into a Transaction object and put it into an array of Transaction object.

```
{
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "user_id": "59",
        "offer_id": "1234"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "user_id": "59",
        "offer_id": "1234"
    }
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
public class Transactions
{
    // what goes here since the "key" field is always different?
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int offer_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are aware that 2 and 3 are objects, not array keys?

Comment: Yes. I am.  Am I missing something here that is completely clear?

Comment: I guess you are skipping the basics in c#, you can't have property names starting with numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify more.  I understand totally property names aren't supposed to start with numbers.  But that's the JSON string given and I guess I am trying to understand how to parse it.

Comment: What is the result you expect? An array of those transaction objects or an object where the keys are the properties?

Comment: I added more details in the description above to make my question clearer.  Basically, I would like an array of transaction objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62722/discussion-between-kyorcode-and-dhana).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the JObject in JSON.Net library.

```
var transactions = JObject.Parse(json).PropertyValues()
                                      .Select(o => o.ToObject<Transaction>());
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `JavaScriptSerializer`, you can handle this by deserializing into a `Dictionary<string, Transaction>`.  From there you can convert it to an array pretty easily if you need to.

Example code:

```
string json = @"
{
    ""2"": {
        ""id"": ""2"",
        ""user_id"": ""59"",
        ""offer_id"": ""1234""
    },
    ""3"": {
        ""id"": ""3"",
        ""user_id"": ""59"",
        ""offer_id"": ""1234""
    }
}";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Transaction>>(json);
var transactions = dict.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();

foreach (Transaction t in transactions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
        "id: {0}, user_id: {1}, offer_id: {2}", t.id, t.user_id, t.offer_id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up that serializing key-value pairs from Javascript to C# is impossible.

I've changed my code and and made a normal array of objects in JS and sent it to the server.

BUT it is possible to parse a key-value pairs form string variable to Dictionary in C# or to a list of KeyValuePair<x,x>

And it is also possible to build a key-value pair using C# and covert it to JSON or JS