# Parsing a string with json

Tags: c#, json

http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.7.2/data/en_US/item.json
This is how my json data looks like.
I would like to parse it. My problem is that in the "data" section, each object ( 1001, 1004, 1006) is a "basic" type :

How do i parse this properly into C# is my question.

Comment: Check out http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Make sure you have valid json, copy your json string to http://json2csharp.com/ and it will let you generate a class. Later use JSON.Net *(or any other)* to deserialize json string to object.

Comment: I have edited my post so my question will be clearer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270990/how-to-parse-json-objects-with-numeric-keys-using-javascriptserializer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Comment: Include the actual JSON in your post, not a picture of it. We can't copy-and-paste from a picture.

Answer (score 0):

First create another class:

```
public class Foo
{
     public List<Basic> Basic{get;set;}
     public string type{get;set;}
     public string version{get;set;}
}
```

Then use [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json),

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(inputString)
```