# C# Get data from twitch api for latest follower using JSON

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net, twitch

Im trying to make a application that get's the latest follower from "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mepphotv/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=0" and save it to a .txt file. I know how would I save the string 'display_name' to a txt file but I don't know how to get that data (display_name). I installed the JSON.NET on Visual Studio and searched the web for a answer but with no luck. Can someone please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net

Comment: Internet is full of tutorials. For example [first result](https://blog.udemy.com/c-sharp-json/) when searching _JSON.NET Tutorial_ in Google.

Comment: Ok so I managed to get the data into a String DownloadData, Now what's the best way to get "display_name" : " ". Here's the code: WebClient client = new WebClient();
String DownloadData = client.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/mepphotv/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=0");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following classes, adapted from the results of posting your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ by using a `Dictionary<string, string>` for the `_links` properties and a `DateTime` for dates:

```
public class User
{
    public long _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public object logo { get; set; }
    public object bio { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Follow
{
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }
    public bool notifications { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject()
    {
        this.follows = new List<Follow>();
    }
    public List<Follow> follows { get; set; }
    public int _total { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> _links { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to deserialize, do:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(DownloadData);
```

To get the latest follower (sorting by `created_at` date) do:

```
        var latestFollow = root.follows.Aggregate((Follow)null, (f1, f2) => (f1 == null || f2 == null ? f1 ?? f2 : f2.created_at > f1.created_at ? f2 : f1));
        var latestName = latestFollow.user.display_name;
```

To sort all followers in reverse by `created_at` date, do:

```
        var sortedFollowers = root.follows.OrderByDescending(f => f.created_at).ToList();
```